# Find all ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Find all the ring homomorphisms $f$ : $\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_3$.

definition of ring homomorphism:

The function f: R → S is a ring homomorphism if:

1) $f(1)$ = $1$

2) $f(a+b)$ = $f(a)$ + $f(b)$ for all a,b, in R

3) $f(ab)$ = $f(a)$ $f(b)$ for all a,b in R

Does it make sense to say that in this case

$f(6) = f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) +f(1) + f(1) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Could you explain what do we do to find ring homomorphism in all cases. Not only $\mathbb{Z}_m \to\mathbb{Z}_n$, where $m<n$ .

Comment: Note that the solution depends upon your definition of ring homomorphism. If you define a ring homomorphism from ring $R$ to ring $S$ as a map $f : R \to S$ such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(x y) = f(x) f(y)$, then $f(0) = 0$ holds, but (provided $R$ and $S$ have a unity) it does not follow that $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti my definition includes $f(1)$ = 1

Comment: Wherever $f$ sends $1$ determines where $f$ sends other elements

Comment: @J.W.Tanner well, in the definition given to me ring homomorphism is a function that sends 1 to 1.

Comment: @Amalya I think your definition is incorrect, because then the zero homomorphism would not exist.

Comment: So then $f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=1+1$, etc.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so then how will I eventually describe the ring homomorphisms?

Comment: you must have $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3=0$, $f(4)=f(1)=1$ and $f(5)=f(2)=2$.

Comment: Please search for your question before asking. Thanks

Comment: @JoelPereira, there are two distinct definitions. If you are working in the category of rings, morphisms are defined as OP does. If you are working in the category of rings with unity, then you additionally require the unity of the first ring to go to the unity of the second ring.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, that really depends on the specific rings we are given.

If you have learned module theory, you will know the way to find all the module homomorphisms is to "send the generators" and then "respect the relations". Because the linearity ensures we take care of all the elements as long as we take care of the generators, while the well-definedness requires the relations to be respected.

This is the basic principle to find homomorphisms, and what you are doing is literally the same. In your case, the ring hom is at first place a $\mathbb{Z}$-module hom, and $1$ is the generator. However, for a general ring, things get a bit harder. But you can do your best by getting familiar with some special cases.

For example, to find a ring hom from a polynomial ring $R[x]\rightarrow S$, it suffices to consider where to send $x$, because that gives the destination for every element. And indeed, in many cases, the ring you have is a quotient of a polynomial ring. In that case, you have some constraints: take care of the well-definedness.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the ring $\mathbb Z_6$ can be obtained by successively adding $1$.

According to your definition, $f(1)=1$ (by (1)),

and $f(n\times1)=n\times f(1)=n\times1$ (by (2) and induction).

(Here $n\times$ means added $n$ (where $n \in \mathbb Z)$ times in the ring,  not multiplication in the ring.)

It does make sense to say that $6$, which is in the additive identity class in $\mathbb Z_6,$

gets mapped to $0$ in $\mathbb Z_3.$